# Keycloak add dynamic user-session-notes in login process

Tags: keycloak, customization

I'm new to Keycloak, and trying to customize login-phase to add dynamic parameters as user-session-notes.

In the legacy system, users login with username, password and additional parameter - lets call it dynamic-parameter.
This dynamic-parameter can be different in each user-login, and depends on the user.
It is being used for security-checks when user sends request to a service.

When moving to Keycloak, I tried to find a way to add dynamic-parameter in login-phase, so when sending request to a service with a token, the service can retrieve that dynamic-parameter and perform the security-checks.
I didn't manage to find a way to do it nicely with Keycloak current capabilities.

Is there any Execution Flow that can be added along UsernamePasswordForm that can achieve this?

The closest things I found about this are threads that suggest self-development of Authenticator:

- [Adding attributes during login](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-November/016231.html)
- [How to add custom information (a session note) in UserSession](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013141.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I created custom authenticator that puts the dynamic parameters as user-session-notes - by implementing Authenticator and AuthenticatorFactory.
Following [How to create custom authenticator](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi_walkthrough).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).