# Retrieving User Session Notes in Keycloak Rest Admin API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

As said in the title, I want to retrieve the user session notes that I set during user authentication using this Admin Rest API endpoint: `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/sessions`.

I have successfully created a custom authenticator as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051306/keycloak-add-dynamic-user-session-notes-in-login-process) and following the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi)

In my custom authenticator i set the user session notes i want

```
    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {

         context.getAuthenticationSession().setUserSessionNote("key", "value");
         
         context.success();
    }
```

But I cant see them using the Admin Rest API endpoint.

I was even able to map these session notes to a claim in my access tokens (and I can see the session notes in the token claims).
But i dont need them in the token, i need to read them from the endpoint.

Is that supposed to work?
Am I missing something?

- [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051306/keycloak-add-dynamic-user-session-notes-in-login-process)
- [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi)

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure if it is expected that this endpoint:

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/sessions
```

in the [Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_users) should return the user's session notes.

So I ended up [adding a custom REST endpoint](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_rest) that returns a [UserSessionModel](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/UserSessionModel.html) which includes the user's session notes:

```
public class UserSessionProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

    private final KeycloakSession session;

    public UserSessionProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @GET()
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response get(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
    
        RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
        UserModel user = session.users().getUserById(realm, userId);

        List<UserSessionModel> sessions = session.sessions().getUserSessionsStream(realm, user).toList();
    
        return Response.ok(sessions).build();
    }

}
```

If anybody knows about a better approach for this, I'd be grateful!

Cheers!